# Replace an XML attribute's value with the value of a shell variable

Tags: sed, variable, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="12/01/2016 17:43:15" REPOSITORY_VERSION="184.93">
<REPOSITORY NAME="PCREPO_BIDEV" VERSION="184" CODEPAGE="UTF-8" 
DATABASETYPE="Oracle">
<FOLDER NAME="ABC" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="SHARED" 
DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="3b13d2c9-39dc-426f-8320- 
def2bb8424ef">
```

I have the above sample data.  In which file will have FOLDER NAME with some value. I have to replace it with some other value which is a variable
I want to replace FOLDER NAME="ABC" with DEF

```
 sed -i "s/<FOLDER NAME=\"\*\"/<FOLDER NAME=\"$FLDR\"/g" Gather.XML
```

Above sed commands doesn't through any error but it is not replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed -i 's/<FOLDER NAME="[A-Z]*"/<FOLDER NAME="'$FLDR'"/g' Gather.XM
```

Comment: This would create broken XML if the value `$FLDR` contained characters that needs encoding, e.g. `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a well-formed XML document, using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER[@NAME="ABC"]/@NAME' -v "$FLDR" file.xml
```

This would locate the `FOLDER` node under `/POWERMART/REPOSITORY` whose `NAME` attribute is `ABC` and change its value to the value of the shell variable `FLDR`.

This would also work if there happened to be a newline between the `FOLDER` node name and the `NAME` attribute, as XML is insensitive to such whitespace.

Example:

```
$ cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="12/01/2016 17:43:15" REPOSITORY_VERSION="184.93">
  <REPOSITORY NAME="PCREPO_BIDEV" VERSION="184" CODEPAGE="UTF-8" DATABASETYPE="Oracle">
    <FOLDER NAME="ABC" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="SHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="3b13d2c9-39dc-426f-8320-def2bb8424ef"/>
  </REPOSITORY>
</POWERMART>

$ FLDR='DEF'
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER[@NAME="ABC"]/@NAME' -v "$FLDR" file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd">
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="12/01/2016 17:43:15" REPOSITORY_VERSION="184.93">
  <REPOSITORY NAME="PCREPO_BIDEV" VERSION="184" CODEPAGE="UTF-8" DATABASETYPE="Oracle">
    <FOLDER NAME="DEF" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="SHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="3b13d2c9-39dc-426f-8320-def2bb8424ef"/>
  </REPOSITORY>
</POWERMART>
```

If you have to match a particular `REPOSITORY`'s `NAME`, then e.g.

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/POWERMART/REPOSITORY[@NAME="PCREPO_BIDEV"]/FOLDER[@NAME="ABC"]/@NAME' -v "$FLDR" file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "`.`" in your sed expression to match all characters

```
 sed -i "s/<FOLDER NAME=\"\.*\"/<FOLDER NAME=\"$FLDR\"/g" Gather.XML
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should do `[^\"]*` instead of `\*`:

```
sed -i "s/<FOLDER NAME=\"[\"]*\"/<FOLDER NAME=\"$FLDR\"/g" Gather.XML
```

Since you want to match all text till the first `"` there. `\*` will match the literal `*` character, but you don't have that there, so the file's contents never match.