# Change XML node's value, using sed?

Tags: sed, xml, xmlstarlet

I have the following node in an XML document:

```
<client-version>1.2.8</client-version>
```

How can I replace replace the node's value, `1.2.8`, with `1.2.9`?

Wanted output:

```
<client-version>1.2.9</client-version>
```

Comment: Related: [Replace an XML attribute's value with the value of a shell variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451936/replace-an-xml-attributes-value-with-the-value-of-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use an XML parser to do this.  For example `xmlstarlet` (a command line XML tool):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//client-version' -v '1.2.9' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<client-version>1.2.9</client-version>
```

The above command would locate *all* occurrences of the `client-version` document node and change their values to the string `1.2.9`.

To only change the ones that are `1.2.8`, you would use

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//client-version[text() = "1.2.8"]' -v '1.2.9' file.xml
```

Redirect the output to a new file, inspect it and rename it to the original filename, or run `xmlstarlet` with its `-L` or `--inplace` options to edit the file in-place.

---

Using `xq`, from `yq`, from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/, which allows you to use `jq` expressions to modify XML documents:

```bsh
xq -x '(..|."client-version"? // empty) |= "1.2.9"' file.xml
```

This updates the value of each `client-version` node to `1.2.9` regardless of where in the document it is located.

The string `1.2.9` could be inserted from a variable like so:

```bsh
new_version=1.2.9
xq -x --arg ver "$new_version" '(..|."client-version"? // empty) |= $ver' file.xml
```

Comment: I'm currently using bamboo to run this script as a task, bamboo is running CENTOS and when I use **xmlstarlet** it says **the command is not found.** Hence why I went down the sed route.

Comment: Running it as a **shell script** on bamboo. CentOS 6. Would **xmlstartlet** be available on this? Do I need to install it first? Apologies I'm a bit new to it.

Comment: @CathalMacDonnacha See, for example, here: [How to instal/setup XMLStarlet in Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/42855905)

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below awk command and it worked fine

```
awk '$0 ~ /^<client-version>/ && $0 ~ /<\/client-version>/{gsub("1.2.8","1.2.9",$0)}1' orginalfile  >temperorayfile && mv temperorayfile  orginalfile
```

Comment: It might work fine once, but it's wrong, so don't use it in production code. It only takes tiny insignificant variations in the formatting of the XML to break it. When working with XML, always use XML-aware tools.

Comment: @user32929 I'm trying to run this as a shell script on bamboo. CentOS 6. Would xmlstartlet be available on this? Do I need to install it first? Apologies I'm a bit new to it.